# True disable of a check box in a DataGridView using DataGridViewCheckboxCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Does anyone know of a way to disable a checkbox in a DataGridView using a DataGridViewCheckboxCell?

I can make it read only, and set the background color, but I can’t get the checkbox itself to appear disabled.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you cast the DataGridViewCheckboxCell into a CheckBox?

Answer (score 2):

Guess [you have to paint by yourself](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/988c7e3f-c172-467d-89b7-b80a60b7f24f). [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171619.aspx) is Microsoft's code sample for disabling buttons using the same technology.