# Inactive checkbox in datagridview VB.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

i added checkbox to `datagridview` like this

```
 Dim CbxColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
                With CbxColumn
                    .HeaderText = ""
                    .Name = "Return"
                    .Width = 50
                End With
                dgvDetail.Columns.Insert(0, CbxColumn)
```

when i run it show correctly  but now i want to disable some rows on dataGridView dynamically not every row just some rows depend on other value in that rows  i mean when column2 have value "Open"                     i try to do like this

```
 For i = 0 To dgvDetail.Rows.Count - 1
                    If dgvDetail.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = "Open" Then
     //I want to do what i expect here//
                        dgvDetail.Rows(i).Cells(1).ReadOnly = True
                    End If
                Next
```

but it's just can't edit value    but i prefer want it to disable as grey color or inactive control like when we set `buttoncontrol.enabled=false`  What should i do Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
 private void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == 1)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell=dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkCell = cell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
        chkCell.Value = false;
        chkCell.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        chkCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray;
        cell.ReadOnly = true;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just disable the cell as you mentioned (readonly), but also set it's `BackColor` :

```
  dgvDetail.Item(1, i).Style.BackColor = Color.LightGray
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by disabling the `DataGridViewCell` as

```
private void enableCell(DataGridViewCell row, bool enabled) {
    //toggle read-only state
    row.ReadOnly = !enabled;
    if (enabled)
    {
        //restore cell style to the default value
        row.Style.BackColor = row.OwningColumn.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
        row.Style.ForeColor = row.OwningColumn.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;
    }
    else { 
        //gray out the cell
        row.Style.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        row.Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray;
    }
}
```

or you can extent the above code to disable the whole `DataGridViewRow` by iterating through each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1626948/1361234

And I found a project to do this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31829/Disabled-Checkbox-Column-in-the-DataGridView

But, I used the method in [@Thirisangu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1460267/thirisangu)'s answer, it can work. Thank you, Thirisangu.

```
    chkCell.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    chkCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray;
    cell.ReadOnly = true;
```